# Is doing a square root once slower than squaring n times?

Tags: c++

I was just looking at some algorithms for prime numbers and came across this:

```
for(int i=2;i*i <= n;i++)
{/*assume no operations here*/}
```

I was just wondering if the above loop will be faster than the following or not?

```
int x=sqrt(n);
for(int i=2;i<=x;i++)
{/*nop*/}
```

Comment: why don't you time it?

Comment: What's the point of the second loop? It's equivalent to `i = x + 1`.

Comment: Depends - for small `n`, it probably will - but in most cases, it won't.

Comment: I would like some explanation to it as well. Also if there exists a particular n above which one becomes faster than the other.

Comment: Reiterating what claptrap said, why don't you write a test that times it, than?

Comment: @sleeping_dragon: then time it. run both methods, sequentially increase the 'space' you're testing, and graph the results. sqrt() has pretty fixed large overhead, but at some point the savings on the testing loop will start paying off.

Comment: It depends on `n`, but in general - second case should be faster.

Comment: Timed it. First one is much slower for bigger values of n (10^5). But for smaller orders the difference doesn't show up even in microseconds. Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the value of `n`, of course. Anyway, `sqrt()` is not guaranteed to give you the right result: due to rounding reasons, you might end up with a value of `x` which is one less than expected and ruin the algorithm. Rather than going for a micro-optimisation, I would stick to correctness here and use the original version, which is guaranteed to give correct results.